# Paging an html-table while maintaining filter options

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter

For a customer we are making a webpages project. This includes a lot of tables with even more records.
I am looking for a client-side way to show only a certain part of the table (be it a TOP 100, records for the past month, something like that), but keeping all the records available for usage by a search filter.

The search filter I am currently using is the one from W3.JS (w3.htmlFilter), but upon loading this still shows over 500 records.

The main objective is described above, but I'd also accept a decent solution which would allow me to display 10 records, without losing the filter optionality.

The table is populated using a foreach that constructs each record based on a collection provided using Razor.

Already tried setting the Table Max-Height and giving it a Y-overflow.
Already tried a display:inline-block, but this destroyed all lay-out.
Already tried some JS, which displayed only certain records, but meant I lost access to the non-displayed records (due to Razor).

To populate my data I use this Razor:

```
@{
    var allFoo = db.GetFoos();
    var foosToShow = foos.Where(v => v.SomeCondition == true);
}
```

The filter applied to the table:

```
<input id="filter" oninput="w3.filterHTML('#foosTable', '.filterItem', this.value)" class="w3-input" placeholder="Search for foo..." />
```

actually populating the records:

```
<tbody>
 @foreach (Foo foo in foosToShow)
 {
 <tr class="filterItem" onclick="TransferElement(this)">
  <td>@foo.Prop1</td>
  <td>@foo.Prop2</td>
  <td>@foo.Prop3</td>
  <td>@foo.Prop4</td>
  <td>@foo.Prop5</td>
  <td>@foo.Prop6</td>
 </tr>
 }
</tbody>
```

Expected Result: Filterable List of X records long, where X can be set.

Comment: I suggest to try out: https://datatables.net/ . It supports filter, ordering, pagination, server side processing and much more. Had great results with it :)

Comment: @Aaron I came across that as well, but as far as I understand it does a server-call on each search? And that isn't really an option considering the server location and connection speed.

Comment: It depends on how you implement it. You can also simply use an array as data source and have all functionality like searching etc. If you need help feel free to leave a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution by using datatables:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var data = [
    [
        "Tiger Nixon",
        "System Architect",
        "Edinburgh"
    ],
    [
        "Garrett Winters",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh"
    ]
]
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {
 data: data
 } );
} );
</script>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Job</th>
   <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The only thing you have to change is the variable data to your array with data.
Everything works without server side processing.
What you could also do: Create a getdata.php file and use this one as data source by echoing the query result as JSON.

For further information: https://datatables.net/manual/data/